# Need to condence data in oracle table

Tags: sql, plsql

```
create table temp_1 (part_number number , application varchar2)
insert into  temp_1 values (10,1997-2004 ford)
insert into  temp_1 values (10,1997-2004 mustand)

select * from temp_1
10 1997-2004 ford
10 1997-2004 mustand
```

---

i want the data to be display like this

```
part number  application 
10,         1997-2004 ford,mustang
```

so far i have tried

```
select LISTAGG(application,'~') WITHIN GROUP (order by part_number)  from temp_1
```

but not getting the desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this done, You need to split the values in application field to `YEAR` and `MAKE`. Here I've split it using `SUBSTR()`.

Assuming that the Year will always be in a fixed format `YYYY-YYYY`.

```
SELECT part_number, 
       YEAR|| listagg(make, ',') within group (order by part_number) application
FROM(
     SELECT part_number, 
            substr(application, 1, 9) YEAR, 
            substr(application, 10, LENGTH(application)) make
     FROM   temp_1
     )
GROUP BY part_number, year;
```

Comment: just to add a question here for my knowledge  what if we have the year format in yyyy-yyyy and yyyy